# Can I write data to Apple HealthKit/ Google-fit in Flutter using Dart

Tags: flutter, healthkit, google-fit, flutter-health

I am using flutter_health plugin for reading data from apple healthkit. Now I am thinking to write data as well. I am not getting APIs to write data on Apple health.
Please help me to know if there is any platform in flutter to write data on Apple health or on Google fit.

Answer (score 2):

For now flutter can only read data from Iphone's Health app. Health kit API is used to read and write data but its only for swift and objective-c or for native development. You can read about it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to write a plugin that does this then? I believe you should be able to write packages in native language: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: I found one (only one) flutter package that allows writing data to Apple Health: https://pub.dev/packages/health_kit_reporter
but no success with Google Fit...